# Regex for repeating series of numbers and number ranges (e.g. 3 digit numbers and 3 digit number ranges)

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm looking for a regex to match repeating number sequences.  The number/range itself could be any three digit number, for e.g.  I want to match

```
345
346-348
234,235,236,237-239
234, 235, 236, 237-239
234,234, 236 and 237-239
234,234, 236 or 237-239
```

I don't want to match

```
3454
111-222-333
454,4567 (match only 454)
```

The number could be any three digit number.  I tried different regexs with \d{3} in the mix, but I've not found anything that works.  Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: I'm confused, how is `345` a repeating number sequence?

Comment: I've read this a few times but cannot work out what the criteria are. Do you mean that you want to match the literal character sequence "346-348" or that you want to match any of "346", "347", and "348"? Why is "345" desired but not "3454"? Can you define "repeating number sequence" more explicitly?

Comment: I was looking to match any three digit number (s) and three digit number ranges

Comment: So you would not want to match the literal character sequence "234, 235, 236, 237-239" but you would want to match any of "234", "235", "236", and/or "237-239"? If so, then I request that you edit your question to simply say that you want to match three-digit numbers and three-digit ranges (technically: closed intervals of numbers, using the hyphen as a bound separator). The term "repeating number sequence" doesn't fit here, in my opinion.

Comment: @Bob76: Is `111-222-333` a valid match also?

Comment: No, 111-222-333 is not a valid match

Comment: ok then make sure you check that input with all the answers below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```sh
^\d{3}(?:-\d{3}$|(?:(?:,\s*\d{3}\s*){1,3}-\d{3})|(?:,\d{3},\s*\d{3}\s*(?:and|or)\s*\d{3}-\d{3})?)*(?=,|$)
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/GtLBKZ/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^\d{3}                   ##Checking from starting of value if value starts from 3 digits.
(?:                      ##Creating 1st capturing group here.
  -\d{3}$|               ##Matching - followed by 3 digits at end of value OR.
  (?:                    ##Creating 2nd capturing group here.
     (?:,\s*\d{3}\s*){1,3} ##In a non-capturing group matching ,\s* followed by 3 digits with \s* and this whole group 3 times.
     -\d{3}              ##Followed by - 3 digits.
  )|                     ##Closing 2nd capturing group OR.
  (?:                    ##Creating 3rd capturing group here.
     ,\d{3},\s*\d{3}\s*  ##Matching , 3 digits, \s* 3 digits \s*
     (?:and|or)          ##Matching and OR or strings in a non-capturing group here.
     \s*\d{3}-\d{3}      ##Matching \s* followed by 3 digits-3digits
  )?                     ##Closing 3rd capturing group keeping it optional.
)                        ##Closing 1st capturing group here.
*(?=,|$)                 ##nd matching its 0 or more matches followed by comma OR end of line.
```

Comment: samples like `111-222-333` are taken care in regex now, those values will not be caught.

Answer (score 5):

You may use this regex:

```sh
^\d{3}(?:-\d{3})?(?:\s*(?:,|and|or)\s*\d{3}(?:-\d{3})?)*(?=,|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NrJWQT/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `\d{3}`: Match 3 digits
- `(?:-\d{3})?`: optionally followed by a hyphen and 3 digits
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
  - `(?:,|and|or)`: Match a comma or `and` or `or`
  - `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
  - `\d{3}`: Match 3 digits
  - `(?:-\d{3})?`: optionally followed by a hyphen and 3 digits
- `)*`: Start non-capture group. Repeat this group 0 or more times
- `(?=,|$)`: Lookahead to assert that we have a comma or End of line ahead of current position

Comment: Works great for the first set of values; however, it does not match the 454 in  454,4567 (match only 454).  Any thoughts?